# Hashtable insert implementation using string key problem

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a problem I've been trying to solve for days now. I try to create a Hashtable from three structs the first one with buckets of pointers to a pair array with key and value pair. The key is supposed to be a string (char * arr). I don't fully grasp how to create a working insert function for it what I aim to do in my code is trying to see if in bucket h there exists a key or not. I feel something is wrong with my logic and syntax. If someone could help me on the way it would be mighty appreciated.

I have looked at hashtable theory on Wikipedia and youtube videos but no one of them uses three structs and string keys. that's where I get stuck I feel.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"hashtable.h"

struct hash_table
{
    Bucket *bucket;
    int hash_size;
};

struct bucket
{
    Pair *list;
    int capacity;
    int size;
};

struct pair
{
    char *key;
    int value;
};

Pair copy_key(char *key, int value)
{
    Pair copy = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
    copy->key = key;
    copy->value = value;
    return copy;
}

unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)          
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}

void hash_insert (HashTable *tab, const char *key, int value)
{
    unsigned long h = hash(key) % tab->hash_size;
    int i = 0;

    while(tab->bucket[h]->list[i]->key != NULL && (i < tab->bucket->size))
    {
        Pair pair = copy_key(key,value);
        if (tab->bucket[h]->list[i]->key == pair->key)
        {
            tab->bucket[h]->list[i]->value == pair->value;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

A working insert function for a three struct layer hashtable with string keys.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve]. Your code at least is not complete. Most important part lacking: How do you initialise your hash table! (Declaration of Pair/Bucket: Well, one can imagine...). Proper formatting would make the code much more readable.

Comment: To me your question is unclear. Maybe it will help if you show us how you initialize the hash table and how you call the insert function. Your current code doesn't seem to insert anything at all

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems in your insertion function:

```
void hash_insert (HashTable *tab, const char *key, int value)
{
    unsigned long h = hash(key) % tab->hash_size;
    int i = 0;

    // depending on how you initialise your hash table, the list might yet
    // be NULL(!) - so you possibly yet need a check for!

    // you need FIRST to check if the index is yet valid, THEN check
    // if there is a key!
    //while(tab->bucket[h]->list[i]->key != NULL && (i < tab->bucket->size))
    while(i < tab->bucket[h].size && tab->bucket[h].list[i].key != NULL)
    // additionally: you have a pointer, index operator [] dereferences
    // -> you have a struct directly -> need to access via .
    {
        //Pair pair = copy_key(key,value);
        // BAD idea: you malloc a struct, but never free it -> memory leak!

        if (tab->bucket[h].list[i].key == /*pair->*/key)
        // compare directly!

        // however: == compares the pointers only - most likely, though,
        // you have created a new string somewhere else just with same
        // CONTENT - in this case you need to compare via strcmp:
        if (strcmp(tab->bucket[h].list[i].key, key) == 0)

        {
            //tab->bucket[h]->list[i]->value == pair->value;
            // comparison? assuming you wanted to assign:
            tab->bucket[h].list[i].value = value;

            return;
        }
    }

    // end of while reached, the key was not yet found!
    // -> you need to insert it here:

    if(i == tab->bucket[h].size)
    {
        // no space in buckets left!
        // -> need to realloc (leaving this to you)

        // BUT: you might want to consider overall fill grade or maximum fill
        // grade for buckets and do a complete re-hash of all contents...
    }

    // assuming we insert in THIS bucket:
    tab->bucket[h].list[i].key = ???;
    tab->bucket[h].list[i].value = value;
}
```

`???` - well, depends. I pretty much assume you want the hash map to own the key strings it contains. Then you are safe from key being a local array going out of scope or a dynamically allocated string being deleted afterwards! So:

```
tab->bucket[h].list[i].key = strdup(key);
```

If you want to avoid unnecessary copies because you allocated the string already, you might add another parameter: `int isTakeOwnwership` (or `bool`, but you need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for):

```
tab->bucket[h].list[i].key = isTakeOwnership ? key : strdup(key);
```

In both examples, I did not check for result of strdup being NULL - you need to do so and handle the case that memory allocation failed (maybe add a return value to your insertion function indicating success or failure?).

Do not forget to `free` the strings in the map on element removal!!! Remember, your map took ownership of.